# CDATA for a value in XML

Tags: xml

How do I add CDATA to the ViolationInfo in this below XML

```
<Violations ViolationNo="1" ViolationCD="10G" ConditionCode="" SectionCd="NYCHC 81.35" severity="0" ViolationInfo="Cold holding equipment not properly maintained in that two door reach-in refrigerator in kitchen observed holding potentially hazardous milk and operating at an internal temperature of 48°F.. All potentially hazardous foods were discarded as per violation 2G" Point="5" Occurence="0" ViolationDate="2/17/2010 7:58:00 AM"></Violations>
```

When I tried to put as shown below I am getting an error saying cannot have < in the value

```
<![CDATA[Facility conditions conducive to the existence of pest life in that several holes, approximately 2-3 inches in diameter noted in ceiling throughout rear food storage area and throughout basement.]]>
```

Comment: CDATA wont work in a node attribute, but is perfectly acceptable in a node value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot put a CDATA section inside a value, nor it is meaningful — values already can only contain text data, you don't need to wrap it inside a CDATA section.

Comment: But when I have a degree symbol in the text it is throwing error saying invalid character.

Comment: Incorrect answer. You can have a CDATA wrapper around a node value. Where you can't have it is as an attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the CDATA and escape the attribute text or move the violation info to its own tag.

```
<Violations>
 <ViolationInfo><![CDATA[Facility conditions conducive to the existence of pest life in that several holes, approximately 2-3 inches in diameter noted in ceiling throughout rear food storage area and throughout basement.]]></ViolationInfo>
</Violations>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. CDATA will not work in an XML node attribute, but will indeed work for the node value itself.